# 'E extends Object declared in class Vector even after using generics

Tags: java, oop, vector, warnings

I have been trying to compile the following code for a lot of time now, but I'm always getting the warning:

```
 warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to addElement(E) as a member of the raw type Vector
  v.addElement(obj);
              ^
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in class Vector
```

This is happening , even though I declared my Vector using generics. Could you please help me out ?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Employee {
    
    String name;
    float sal;
    int id;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Vector<Employee> vec = new Vector<Employee>();
        int n, ch;
        System.out.println("Enter the number of employees");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        n = sc.nextInt();
        Create(vec, n);
        System.out.println("Enter any 1 of the following choices ");
        System.out.println("1 to insert a new record");
        System.out.println("2 to delete an Employee record by name");
        System.out.println("3 to delete by the ID");
        ch = sc.nextInt();
        switch (ch) {
            case 1:
                {

                }
            case 2:
                {

                }
        }
    }

    public static void Create(Vector v, int n) {
        String ename;
        float esal;
        int eid;
        int i;
        Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter the ID");
            eid = sc1.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter the name");
            ename = sc1.next();
            System.out.println("Enter the salary");
            esal = sc1.nextFloat();
            Employee obj = new Employee();
            obj.name = ename;
            obj.sal = esal;
            obj.id = eid;
            v.addElement(obj);

        }

    }
}
```

In this program, I have declared a class `Employee` and aim to call the `Create` method `n` times for adding the details of `n` employees before and then performing other functions.
However I initiially got the Xlint:unhecked warning and after compiling it again with Xlint:unchecked filename I'm still getting this warning and am not able to proceed further. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument `v` in your `Create` method is declared as a raw type.
Try adding the generic type to the parameter declaration, e.g.:

`public static void Create(Vector<Employee> v, int n) {`

You can read more about raw types in the following link:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html

Comment: Thank you so very much !! This solved my problem !!